# how do I write a scaffold in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, ruby-on-rails-3.1, scaffolding

I want to write a rails gem that can scaffold a working prototype of the basic functionality of the gem and I was wondering if anyone can explain the process. I know this is a broad topic but I'm hoping for some pointers to tutorials or other rails docs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like most problems I try to solve with rails, there's already a great project that helps you create "starter apps" with rails. [Rails Apps](http://railsapps.github.org/) helps you create application templates that you can then use to generate starter apps. There are some great examples (i.e. devise + rspec + cucumber) to get you started.